# Is there an API for code editing in Cocoa?

Tags: macos, cocoa, editor

I've been exploring various text editor solutions for Mac OS X recently, and I've noticed that some editors, namely Xcode, Smultron and CodeRunner, show the same behavior with bracket matching, which makes the matching bracket exhibit a small yellow popping animation that looked exactly the same throughout the editors. This made me think about whether there is a unified Cocoa API for code views that is being used. I have looked for something like that but I haven't found anything. Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 1):

There is no unified Cocoa API for code views, no, or at least not that I am aware of.  The yellow popping animation is just due to the Cocoa method `-[NSTextView showFindIndicatorForRange:]`, which lots of different code editors use for producing that sort of effect.  However, if you search stackoverflow you'll find some examples of how to do syntax coloring, bracket matching, etc.  You might also find the source code in this project useful: https://github.com/MesserLab/SLiM.  (Which happens to be a project I work on.)